# How to Disable Single Folder in a Folder Becoming Combined in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can you disable single folder in a parent folder being combined into one in VSCode?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncheck `Compact Folders` in the VS Code Settings

[image]